# Can I use the Cook´s Distance to find outliers in a GAM?

Tags: outliers, generalized-additive-model

Can I use the Cook´s Distance to find outliers in a GAM with binomial family?

I have seen that is often used to find outliers in GLM but I did not find an application example for GAM. I therefore suspect that the cook´s distance may not be useful for a GAM.

Answer (score 3):

In principle, yes, but I suspect whether you can do this in practice will depend on exactly how the GAM is implemented and whether you can access the hat matrix of the model.

For GAMs fitted as GLMs via penalised likelihood, you could use the approximation of Cook's D derived for GLMs, which uses the standardised Pearson residuals in place of the standardised residual:

$$D_i = \frac{e^2_{PS_i}}{k + 1} \times \frac{h_i}{1 - h_i}$$

where $e^2_{PS_i}$ is the squared standardised Pearson residual, $k$ is the number of parameters, and $h$ are the hat values.

With the **mgcv** package in R, for example, the hat values can be extracted from a fitted GAM model object via the `influence.gam` method.

I'm not familiar with examples where people use this in a GAM, but the methods for GLMs are described in textbooks.